# How to make a image converter?

Tags: image

I have searched in google and found that there are various image converter that convert images into other file formats. I want to know how they do it, what data gets converted to what. I don't want to create a converter using VB or any other programming language. Instead, I want to learn the full process from scratch so that I can play with the image file as I want. I need a lead.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very big topic. Check [FFmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) which is a free and open source multimedia library that includes converting from and to almost all image formats.